# Como hacer un id dinámico dentro de un ng-repeat que afecta a un ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tengo un botón que lo que hace es sumar un valor al darle click lo realiza con el método ng-click de AngularJS (Angular 1).

1.Este es el Código del Controller js.

```
  $scope.marcadorcasa = 0;

  $scope.sumamarcador = function(partidoid){
    $scope.marcadorcasa = $scope.marcadorcasa +1;        
  };

  $scope.restamarcador = function(partidoid){
    if($scope.marcadorcasa>0){
      $scope.marcadorcasa = $scope.marcadorcasa -1;        
    }

  };
```

2. Esta es mi vista.

   ```
   <div class="col-sm-5 back_marcador spd spi input-group">

   <input type="text" id="form_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="marcadorcasa" min="0" step="1">

    <span class="input-group-btn btn_menos">                                 
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="restamarcador()"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="input-group-btn btn_mas" >
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sumamarcador()"></button>                                                            
    </span>
   </div>
   ```
3. MI problema es que Cuando hago click para sumar el marcador(el valor del input) se suma en cada uno de los input que tengo por el ng-repeat. mi duda es como lograr que el model sea dinámico prove con `$index` pero no logro resolverlo de esa manera.
4. El repeat se ejecuta en el array que me trae esta API

   ```
     $http.get('/api/v1/partidoshoy')          
    .success(function(partidoshoy){
        $scope.partidoshoy = partidoshoy.datos;
        $scope.cargador = ! $scope.cargador;
    }).error(function(error){
          $scope.error = error;

   })
   ```
5. En mi vista el `repeat` se ejecuta de esta manera. El primer `repeat` lo que hace es cargar la ligas y ordenar partido por liga. Y en el segundo `repeat` se ejecuta la carga de partido por liga osea que si en una liga hay 5 partidos se cargar esos partidos de esa liga y si hay partidos de otra liga aparecerán abajo. no aparecen partidos mezclados por liga.

   ```
   <div class="caja_liga" ng-repeat="partidohoy in partidoshoy" ng-if="partidohoy.partido_hoy!=''"> 
      <div class="caja_partido spd spi" ng-repeat="partido in partidohoy.partido_hoy">
           <div class="col-sm-5 back_marcador spd spi input-group">

           <input type="text" id="form_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="marcadorcasa" min="0" step="1">

           <span class="input-group-btn btn_menos">                                 
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="restamarcador()">
            </button>
           </span>

           <span class="input-group-btn btn_mas" >
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sumamarcador()">
            </button>                                                            
            </span>
          </div> 

         </div>           
      </div>
   ```

Comment: ¿Donde está el `ng-repeat`? Sobre que iteras? Si necesitas un `marcadorcasa` por cada iteración, necesitarías tener una lista de marcadores, cosa que no veo. Puedes añadir donde se hace el `ng-repeat` y si es posible donde se carga la lista/array por la/el que iteras?

Comment: claro, mira los datos los obtengo de un array por medio de un api y un metodo http de angujar.

Answer (score 0):

Cuanto estás trabajando en una array de objetos como este, una posible solución sería que cada objeto tenga su propio marcador:

```
<div class="caja_liga" ng-repeat="partidohoy in partidoshoy" ng-if="partidohoy.partido_hoy!=''"> 
   <div class="caja_partido spd spi" ng-repeat="partido in partidohoy.partido_hoy">
        <div class="col-sm-5 back_marcador spd spi input-group">

        <input type="text" id="form_@{{ $index }}" ng-model="partido.marcador" min="0" step="1">

        <span class="input-group-btn btn_menos">                                 
         <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="partido.marcador--">
         </button>
        </span>

        <span class="input-group-btn btn_mas" >
         <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="partido.marcador++">
         </button>                                                            
         </span>
       </div> 

      </div>           
   </div>
```

Se puede hacer también en la función la operación:

```
-- HTML
ng-click="sumarmarcador(partido)"

-- CONTROLLER
$scope.sumamarcador = function(partido){

    partido.marcador = partido.marcador +1;        
  };
```

Una aclaración, marcador no va a existir en el objeto inicialmente, tenés algunas opciones para resolver esto; al momento de buscarlo en la base podés crear esta propiedad en 0, podés también inicializarla con ng-init o cuando ingresas a la función verificar si es undefined y crearla en el momento.

Espero que te sirva, cualquier cosa que no se entienda, no dudes en volver a preguntar.